# What does this means in this context? 「ぁんだよ、手応えねぇなぁ～……」( A girl said this after she killed a demon and saved MC)

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**Context: MC is facing against 3 monsters/ demons at night, and he's about to lose the battle. But then a girl rush in , killed 2 demons with her spear and saved MC. He's very surprised ad don't know what to say.**

**Hope someone can explain to me the meaning + grammar of this sentence : 「ぁんだよ、手応えねぇなぁ～……」 (the girl speaks with a weird dialect + no subject in the sentence so it's hard for me to understand. I can only guess :"The hell ...You guys are so weak ..." )**

More context:

静寂を切り裂くかのような高い声。その声が響き渡るのと同時に、俺の傍を黄金の旋風が走り抜けていった。

？？？「汚物は全殺だぁぁぁーーーーーーっ！」

物騒な雄叫びを上げながら現れた金色の暴風が、背丈の倍はあろうかという棒を振りかざし、事も無げに一閃を繰り出した。

？？？「おら、次ぃ！」

MC「なっ……」

突如現れた金色の暴風───その正体が分かり、俺は言葉を失ってしまった。

MC「おんな……のこ？」

身の丈の二倍はあろう長い槍を軽々と掲げ、夜風に髪を靡かせて仁王のように立っている姿が、月光を浴びて、やけに鮮明に網膜に焼き付いた。

**Girl「ぁんだよ、手応えねぇなぁ～……」**

Monster/Demon「グ、グルルッ……」

Girl「はぁー、つまんね。……おまえもさっさとぶっ殺してやるから、そこで大人しくしとけ」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ぁんだよ is a version of なんだよ. It is more slurred than dialectical, where the な is almost dropped.

Depending on the way of pronunciation (or transcription) and contexts, なんだよ can also be

- あんだよ
- んだよ
- っんだよ

なんだよ literally means "What?", expressing surprise/disappointment.

I don't know what exactly corresponds to 手応え in English, but literally it is like *tangible response* (note 反**応**). In the particular case, it means attack from the enemy (as response to the girl's attack). So 手応えがない means *weak*, as you understand.

Overall, the phrase translates like *what? is this it?*.

Comment: but the girl attack the monsters 1st ? Like she made a surprised attack

Comment: @casualreader It wouldn't matter. Whichever is the first to attack, a strong enough (手応えのある) monster would fight back. So more precisely, 手応えがない is *too easy* rather than *weak*. It describes a property of *fighting* with them rather than of monsters themselves.

Comment: oh so she meant something like : "The hell ....This fight end so fast ~ / I didn't even break a sweat ~"

Comment: @casualreader Yes. FYI 歯応えがある means *hard, stiff* for food, the opposite  of which is things like tofu.

Comment: thanks , i thought at first that she's talking about the monsters